# Inserting nothing into primary auto increment key in Derby database

Tags: java, database, derby

I created table in Derby database that looks something like that:

```sql
create table "DATABASE".SOMETABLE (ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY,
                                   SOMETHING VARCHAR(50) not null)
```

Now I would like to be able to insert into that table without specifically listing all the columns I want to insert into. So I would like to do something like this:

```sql
insert into sometable values ('','something')
```

I don't want to insert anything into id column but I don't want to be forced to always list names of all the columns I want to insert into. However if I execute this code I get error for trying to modify auto increment primary key.
In MySQL and many other database systems I could just do this:

```sql
insert into sometable values ('','something')
```

and it would work but Derby gives me an error. I tried putting NULL instead of '' but I just get the same error. Is there any way to not insert anything into the primary key column with auto increment (without specifically listing all the other columns) in Derby database?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: "*In MySQL and many other database systems I could just do this:*" - no. Only MySQL allows that. Standard SQL won't allow you to store a string value into an integer column. And a column defined as `generated always` can't be populated like that to beg with. You would have to at least specify `overriding system values` to avoid generating a new value, but then you would also have to provide a valid (and unique) integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
insert into sometable values (default, 'something')
```

The default keyword is documented [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the column you're inserting:

```
insert into sometable (something) values ('something')
```

(I would recommend specifying columns in general, then the order of the columns in your DDL does not matter)

Comment: I agree that specifying columns is the best way to go about it, but the OP asked if there's a way to do it without specifying column names